# Is it possible for an element to take up full width while remaining in vertical flow?

Tags: css

So I have an element (actually an iframe) which is enclosed by other elements with padding and margin so it does not naturally take up 100% width.

I would like that element to pop out of its positioning horizontally and take up 100% width while still remaining in the horizontal flow of the document.

Is this possible?

Comment: A code example to get an idea about the structur of your code/elements would be really helpful to help.

Answer (score 0):

using the css unit `vw` might help.

for example:

```
iframe {
    width: 25vw;
}
```

Comment: That has indeed helped, so the width is now set correctly. However the iframe starts after the left margin and then continues off the right side of the screen. I can set margin-left:-30px; but I don't know in advance how much margin to give it. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: sorry, i didn’t get you. 
i didn’t understand what you really want....